# How to calculate points, if there are more than 10 cards

Tags: cv

In Curriculum Vitae (CV) the points calculation is presented in the table only for 1,2,...10 cards. It's easy to see, that in this table the nth card is worth n points.

> First, count the points from the number of relationship, health and knowledge cards owned. Points for these cards are gained according to the table.
> [image: Score table]

On the other hand in polish rule book we can find a sentence [translated]:

> The player will gain more points, if he have more cards. The punctation is showed in the table.

The instruction says, that the calculation is presented in the table, but also says , that more cards = more points. Does that mean, that it's capped on 55 points for 10 cards? Or may I continue counting (66 for 11, 78 for 12,...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer answered [in this post on BGG](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1351515/article/18903163#18903163) that the max score for a set is for the 10-set (55 points):

> Scoring is capped on 10 so if you have 10 you can buy more only to block the opponent form [sic] getting them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems, that I've to subtract some points from my previous score. Anyway after subtraction I still have more than 100 points - my highest score so far :)